# How to perform multiplication in django model?

Tags: django, django-models

This is my model:

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    Quantity    = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    rate        = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
    Amount      = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
```

I want to perform multiplication between Quantity and rate and store the result in Amount...

So I have done something like this:

```
from django.db.models import F

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Purchase)
def update_amount(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
    totalamount = Purchase.objects.get(F('rate') * F('Quantity'))
    instance.Amount = totalamount
```

But its giving me this error:

```
'CombinedExpression' object is not iterable
```

Do anyone have any idea how to do this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But here you already *have* the instance, so the `totalamount` is simply:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Purchase)
def update_amount(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.Amount = instance.rate * instance.Quantity
```

That being said, if the `Amount` is *always* the `rate` multiplied with the `Quantity`, it is better to define a `@property`, since then you avoid data duplication, like:

```
class Purchase(models.Model):

    Quantity    = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    rate        = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)

    def amount(self):
        return self.Quantity * self.rate
```

Comment: No I have to store the amount in a model object because I do have to use it in other models...But If I do the solution which you provided first it is throwing me this error  '    value = value.quantize(decimal.Decimal(".1") ** decimal_places, context=cont
ext)
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]'

Comment: @NiladryKar: this is because the result is too large to store in a `DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)`, see here https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24636

Comment: Yeah I got that,...When I use PositiveIntegerField() it is running...But is there any solution to run it when we are using DecimalField?

Comment: @NiladryKar: increase the `max_digits`, since the number is simply too large (probably larger than 100).